# мультипликативные функции на си. Поиск ошибки

Tags: c, теория-чисел

Задание. Требуется составить программу, которая для любого натурального числа a находит значения мультипликативных функций τ(a), s(a), ϕ(a), где τ(a) — количество всех делителей числа a, s(a) — сумма всех делителей числа a, ϕ(a) — функция Эйлера. Входные данные: a ∈N 
Выходные данные: τ(a), s(a), ϕ(a).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int kol_del(int a)//кол-во делителей числа а
{
    int count=0;
    if(a!=0)
        {
    for(int i=0; i<=a; i++)
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    }
    return count;
}


int sum(int a)
{
    int sum=a;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int eyler(int a)
{
    int ans;
    ans= a;
    for(int i=2; i*i<=a; i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            while(a%i==0)
            {
                a/=i;
                ans-=ans/i;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a > 1)
    ans-=ans/a;
    return ans;
}


int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("VVedite a: %d");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nkol-vo delitelei: %d", kol_del(a));
    printf("\nSumma delitelei chisla a: %d", sum(a));
    printf("\nF-ia Eylera: %d", eyler(a));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Код не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И? В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Код не работает

Comment: Что такое  "не работает"?

Comment: @AnT , видимо висит :)

Comment: Ну прежде чем лезть на форум потратьте 5 минут и прочтите справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - особенно по части поиска ошибок и учебных заданий

Answer (score 2):

Ну, начнем с того, что ваш код медленный и удивительно неэффективный... но, это второй вопрос.

Начинается он с того, что этой строкой

```
printf("VVedite a: %d");
```

он выводит какой-то мусор и ждет вашего ввода. Зачем этот мусор? Но, надеюсь, вы что-то ввели (по скриншоту этого не видно!) - и что будет дальше, скажем, в

```
for(int i=0; i<=a; i++)
{
    if(a % i == 0)
```

Что даст `a%i` для первой же итерации, когда `i` равно нулю?

Дальше пояснять не нужно?

Вы бы и сами могли это понять, если бы не бросились спрашивать, а минимально попытались отладить код...

Comment: В том то и дело, что ввести число не удается. И не знаю, что с этим делать.. а в цикле я так понимаю, что надо начинать с 1?

Comment: Что значит "не удается"? Вы пробовали его вводить?

Comment: При запуске выходит строка: Vvedite a: , и там где нужно вводить число уже стоит шестизначное число

Comment: Как все запущено... Вы же сами выводите это число! Что тут написано? `printf("VVedite a: %d");`? Вывести "VVedite a: ", какое-то число, которое вы не передаете. Оно выводит. Дальше следующая строка - `scanf("%d", &a);` - прочесть `a`. Ждет. Вы не вводите. Она ждет. Вы не вводите... Что вы от программы хотите? При этом я вам в ответе ясно написал: *он выводит какой-то мусор и ждет вашего ввода. Зачем этот мусор?* Ну хоть немного голову-то включайте!!